# Webpack plugin for post processing a CSS file

Tags: css, webpack, plugins

I'm using the [webfonts-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfonts-loader) with webpack. It creates webfonts from .svg-files, but it also creates CSS classes for each icon:

```css
.icon:before {
    font-family: icons !important;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.icon-add-to-list:before {
    content: "\f101";
}
.icon-add-user:before {
    content: "\f102";
}
.icon-address:before {
    content: "\f103";
}
/* ... (200+ CSS-classes) */
```

The icon classes are not required, if the fonts contain ligatures.Then you can use this code:

```
i.icon {
    font-family: icons;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}

<i class="icon">add-to-list</i>
```

There's no option available for turning off the classes.
A way to get rid of them would be replacing them by a regexp:

```js
const regexp = /\.[a-z\-]+:before\s\{[^}]+}\s*/mg;
const newCss = oldCSS.replace(regexp, '');
```

But I need a webpack plugin which can do the replacement. Either using an existing one or writing a own one which rewrites the css code produced by the webfonts-loader.

Answer (score 0):

With the `regexp-replace-loader` it works:

```js
  {
    test: /\.font\.js$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          url: false
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'regexp-replace-loader',
        options: {
          match: {
            pattern: '\\.[a-z0-9\\-]+:before\\s+\\{[^\\}]+\\}\\s*',
            flags: 'mg'
          },
          replaceWith: ''
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'webfonts-loader',
        options: { }
      }
    ]
  },
```